# How to read contents of file into string in C++

Tags: c++, file, compare, buffer

I want to read the all the contents of a file into a string or some other method that would allow me to compare two files. I am looking for files that are exact matches.

Just a little snippet of how I am opening the file and read how many characters it has. which I use to compare to other files to check if it is necessary to compare the whole contents.

Is there a way I can just compare the two buffers?

```
 char buf[1000];
 string str;
 ssize_t numread; 

    cout<<"Enter in the full file path: ";

    getline(cin,str);

    int f1= open(str.c_str(), O_RDONLY);

        if(f1 ==-1){
            cout<<"file did not open"<<'\t'<<errno<<str<<endl;
        }

    int size= tell(f1);
    lseek(f1,0,SEEK_SET);
    numread= read(f1,buf,size);

        if(numread==-1){
            cout<<errno<<endl;
        }

    cout<<'\t'<<":"<<str<<" #Chars:"<<numread<<endl;

    close(f1);
```

Comment: if I've understood correctly your end goal is to compare a bunch of files based on their content. If that's the case you may want to compare the file's digests instead of their content to see if they match.

Comment: @Eugen, to produce a digest, the whole file must be read anyway, may as well compare when reading... Only way it would be faster is if you compare one file agaist many, where the digest can be reused.

Comment: @Evan: that's what I was referring to when I said: "compare a bunch of files based on their content".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a memory mapped file for this.
With UNIX mmap() With Windows MapViewOfFile().
This will give you a pointer in memory that maps to the contents of the file.
Why is this a good idea?
You don't need to allocate space for the file using malloc() or new().
The files can be any size, ok 32bit limit, but there should be a 64bit version.
You can compare the files using

memcmp(file1, file2, sizeoffile1)

Enjoy...

edit - added some code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
cmpfile(char *file1, char *file2)
{
  int result = -1;
  int fd1, fd2;
  off_t size1, size2;
  char *ptr1, *ptr2;

  fd1 = open(file1, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd1 == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' - %s\n", file1, strerror(errno));
    goto error1;
  }

  fd2 = open(file2, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd2 == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' - %s\n", file2, strerror(errno));
    goto error2;
  }

  size1 = lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_END);
  if (size1 == (off_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to seek to end of file '%s' - %s\n", file1, strerror(errno));
    goto error3;
  }

  size2 = lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_END);
  if (size2 == (off_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to seek to end of file '%s' - %s\n", file2, strerror(errno));
    goto error4;
  }

  if (size1 != size2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File sizes mimatched\n");
    goto error5;
  }

  ptr1 = mmap((void *)0, size1, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd1, 0);
  if (ptr1 == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to map file '%s' - %s\n", file1, strerror(errno));
    goto error6;
  }

  ptr2 = mmap((void *)0, size2, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd2, 0);
  if (ptr2 == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to map file '%s' - %s\n", file2, strerror(errno));
    goto error7;
  }

  if (memcmp(ptr1, ptr2, size1) == 0) {
    result = 0;
  }

  munmap(ptr2, size2);
error7:
  munmap(ptr1, size1);
error6:
error5:
error4:
error3:
  close(fd2);
error2:
  close(fd1);
error1:

  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int result = -1;

  if (argc == 3) {
    result = cmpfile(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
      printf("Files match\n");
    } else {
      printf("Files don't match\n");
    }

  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file1> <file2>\n", argv[0]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am geting a compile error saying memcmp was not declared in this scope.. I have it within a function like this : void dir_traverse(const std::string& path, std::ostream& out) and am using it like this int n;
      n=memcmp(buf1, buf2, numread);

Comment: nice use of goto statements.  if you want to do this in c++ you should probably use fstreams and iterators.  Boost.Spirit has a file_iterator type which abstracts away the messy C memory mapping boilerplate, and has the nice bonus of being cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `istreambuf_iterator`, as [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/) on cplusplus.com.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

int main (int ac, char **av) {
  if(ac != 3)
    throw(std::runtime_error("Usage: progname file1 file2"));

  if(std::equal(
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(
        std::ifstream(av[1], std::ios::binary).rdbuf()),
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(
        std::ifstream(av[2], std::ios::binary).rdbuf()))) {
    std::cout << "same\n";
    return 0;
  } else {
    std::cout << "different\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```